# Custom themed Opencart 1.4.8 version to 1.5.1.2

Tags: php, opencart

I have attempted to upgrade Opencart 1.4.8 with custom theme using update script but it deleted the custom theme as it was actually set as default theme. How can I prevent this from happening so I can use this same theme for new version 1.5.1.2?

Also will this custom theme be compatible with 1.5.1.2 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it wont. The only way to stop it is to create a custom theme and set it to that. You don't need to copy all files over, but a few usually like header.tpl, footer.tpl and a stylesheet, then if you make any customisations, either use vQmod or create that tpl file in your theme folder, and copy the content over, then edit